# User Session Management in android

Tags: android, session

I want to maintain user session once the user logs into his/her account so that they are logged in even after the application is closed and started again. Searching on Google and SO, people referred SharedPreferences. I understand that I have to store user details in SP(SharedPreferences), but what if the user updates his/her data? Plus, the HttpGet call I send to the link to get user data returns the valid data(JSON) only when the user is logged in. Is SP the only way to do this, or is there other and more efficient way to do this?

P.S. - I am working as a freelance for a startup, and they have API to their PHP website. I have to make an android app for their website. To log in the user to the website, I make a Http POST call to their API and the result I get is a JSON. If the JSON contains "success" value to the "result" key, then the user is logged in. But as soon as I use intent to go to the next activity(where I have to display the user data by making Http Get call to another API, which only works if the user is logged in), the session is lost. Since I work as a freelance, they don't really trust me giving cookies to user sessions. So, I was hoping there might me some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use cookies (with, say, an authentication token?), Android OS manages them for your app automatically - as long as the cookie is correctly set by the server (ex. expiration date) your app should work fine. But this is a little old school.

A more modern way is to use OAuth or integrate an already existing login system (Facebook, Google, etc.) to authenticate users.

Using Shared Preferences is a wrong tool for this job. It's a workaround for doing proper authentication. There are ways that are trustworthy and secure and take care of all kinds of edge cases, and while it takes a little bit of work to set up, it's a much better option, IMO.

Comment: At first I thought about the Gmail login to their app , but they don't want that right now.

Comment: Could you explain why Shared Preferences is a wrong tool for this job ?

Comment: What are these other ways you hint about ?

Comment: @StephaneEybert here is another related question , may be you can help? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484122/how-to-send-cookies-with-httpget-call-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should try to integrate android AccountManger APIs because storing the credentials in shared preferences is not especially desirable from security point,especially if your app is going to run on rooted devices.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html):

> public class AccountManager extends Object java.lang.Object    ↳
>     android.accounts.AccountManager Class Overview
>
> This class provides access to a centralized registry of the user's
>   online accounts. The user enters credentials (username and password)
>   once per account, granting applications access to online resources
>   with "one-click" approval.
>
> Different online services have different ways of handling accounts and
>   authentication, so the account manager uses pluggable authenticator
>   modules for different account types. Authenticators (which may be
>   written by third parties) handle the actual details of validating
>   account credentials and storing account information. For example,
>   Google, Facebook, and Microsoft Exchange each have their own
>   authenticator.
>
> Many servers support some notion of an authentication token, which can
>   be used to authenticate a request to the server without sending the
>   user's actual password. (Auth tokens are normally created with a
>   separate request which does include the user's credentials.)
>   AccountManager can generate auth tokens for applications, so the
>   application doesn't need to handle passwords directly. Auth tokens are
>   normally reusable and cached by AccountManager, but must be refreshed
>   periodically. It's the responsibility of applications to invalidate
>   auth tokens when they stop working so the AccountManager knows it
>   needs to regenerate them.
>   \